Possibly NSFW? What is an 既成事実?

彼女たちは根掘り葉掘り俺の境遇を聞いてきた。そして俺の話を聞いた後で、みんな声をそろえて言ったよ。可哀想に、私が慰めてあげる....
そう言いながら近づいてきて、『既成事実』を作ろうとする奴らの多いこと多いこと

The character explains this, that he talks to girls about his family etc and the all consoled him. Then he says that they tried to get close to  him and many girls tried to make an 既成事実? What is it? Is it some kind of slang?

既成事実 is not just an "established fact"; it often carries the connotation that something was done without proper consensus or procedures, but it's already irreversible. For example, if someone buys a car while their family is still discussing whether to buy it, this sneaky action is referred to as 既成事実化. This usage is not slangy at all.
既成事実 does not always have a sexual connotation, but it is often used in romance-related contexts. In such cases, it automatically refers to a physical relationship established before officially dating. In this sense, 既成事実 might be considered a type of slang. For example, getting someone drunk and then establishing a physical relationship with them, thereby creating an atmosphere where it's difficult to refuse a more serious relationship, is called 既成事実を作る.

In the context of romance, when the word is used more commonly it is referring to being pregnant before marriage.

Often referred to in "English" as a fait accompli. This carries the nuance that it was done without proper consensus.

@JesseCasman Thanks, learnt a new word today!  But from a quick search, "fait accompli" is almost exclusively used on articles on politics.  Combined with the french roots of the word I believe that it has a formal, academic, usually negative feeling, tone or nuance to it.  Am I right on this?

If I am right on this, the french-originated word can carry a slightly different feel, depending on the context.

"For example, getting someone drunk and then establishing a physical relationship with them"... that's rape.

@ed9w2in6 I think you're correct, most usage of fait accompli is in politics and business.

@nonchip I'm sorry, how is your comment contributing to the discussion? I can't see it.
